# Questionable transformation of a rational function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Studying for my finals right now and going through some exercises. What's supposed to be calculated in this one is the  maximum surface area that you get when forming a triangle out of two arrays of straight lines.

The function I get is $\dfrac{-t^2+t-6.5}{t^2-t-6}$
However, in the solutions, he transforms this function into $-1-\dfrac{12.5}{(t+2)(t-3)}$

What he did with the denominator is obvious, however I haven't the faintest what he did with the numerator to get to the 12.5 or how he got rid of the t in the numerator. He proceeds to calculate further with this function, and before continuing I feel I have to get how he did this.

Comment: Should the middle term in your first fraction be $+6t$?

Comment: Only t, typing mistake.

Comment: Two typing errors in the same line, terribly sorry. Does changing it to $-t$ in the denominator change anything?

Comment: Yes, it does. Do you know about polynomial long division?

Comment: Write the numerator as $-t^2 + t + 6 - 12.5$.

Comment: I do @Git Gud. So, 12,5 is nothing more than the rest of the polynomial division? That does indeed make sense.

Comment: @Dschib Yes (sort of, it's not exactly 12.5), see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278481/how-to-show-that-fracx2x-1-simplifies-to-x-frac1x-1-1) for a similar question. I suggest you answer your own question so this doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest of methods don't occur to you at once. Thank you for bringing it back to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, what needed to be done was polynomial division. My lecturer didn't write down that he wrote the numerator as $-t^2+t+6-12.5$, with $-t^2+t+6$ being the same as the denominator, only multiplied by $-1$. What happens to be left over in this case is $12.5$ though, which has to be divided by the denominator in the polynomial division, hence  $-\dfrac{12.5}{t^2-t-6}$.